# Upgrading gdb for use in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, gdb

The latest version of Qt installs gdb version 7.1. This has an annoying bug: it evaluates certain perfectly valid expressions as `<unavailable synchronous data>`. Apparently this has been fixed in gdb version 7.2, so I downloaded the latest gdb.exe and copied it to `Qt\pythongdb\gdb-i686-pc-mingw32.exe`. Alas, this was not a success: enums were evaluated as `<anonymous enum>` instead of (say) `myHelpfulEnumVal`, and `(void*)p` was evaluated as `void*` instead of (say) `cbf56e0`. So I reverted to gdb version 7.1.
Does anybody know what else I have to do to integrate gdb 7.2 with Qt Creator? Or is it simply not implemented yet?
I am using minGW under Windows 7.

**Update** I have done as Stephen Chu suggests, and am now using Qt Creator 2.2 with gdb 7.2. It seems to work fine. But I had to work out how to tell Qt Creator where to find gdb, because the way to do this has changed: Go to `Tools -> Options -> Tool Chains`. You should see (at least, I did, using mingw under Windows) an `Auto-detected` list and a `Manual` list. The `Manual` list contains a single item:

`MinGW from Simulator Qt for MinGW 4.4 (Qt SDK)`

Click on this, and you can enter the path to `gdb` in the `Debugger:` field. In my case, this is

`C:\Qt\qtcreator-2.1.81\pythongdb\gdb-i686-pc-mingw32.exe`

HTH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creator 2.2 includes gdb 7.2. So you can download and try the snapshots here: ftp://ftp.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator/snapshots/latest/

I don't know if you can copy the gdb from 2.2 and use it in 2.1. But it's worth a try. I use 2.2 snapshots since it's stable enough right now.

Comment: Actually, even with 7.2 in Creator 2.2, I still see this unavailable synchronous data issue sometimes. Like, right now. :) So it may not be gdb's issue but Creator itself.

Comment: Which version of g++ is included in the latest Creator2.2? If it's 4.5, I might take the risk.

Comment: It's still 4.4. I think they need to keep it the same as the current Qt binary builds.