# QT with debugger

Tags: qt, qt4

I am new to QT

I downloaded online installer for QT windows in the location

http://qt.nokia.com/downloads

I just tried simple program like printin hello world.

I Could execute the program. But I am not able to debug it.
I am getting errors like

> None of the debugger engines 'Cdb engine, Gdb engine' capable of
>   debugging binaries of the type 'x86-windows-msvc2008-pe-32bit' is
>   configured correctly.

Should I download a different version for debugging or Did I miss any procedure to include debuging facility?. Please help me to install QT with debugger.

Comment: I tried with QT Creatot itself

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Visual Studio installed? 
You need to have it installed so you can use this engines to debug.

Here is the link for the Visual studio: [LINK](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express)

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with QtCreator. An Update of the QtSDK solved it for me. You find the update mechanism in a menu of QtCreator.

Comment: I started the updater and installed MingW. I got Warning like the following  "The preferred debugger engine for debugging binaries of type 'x86-windows-msvc2008-pe-32bit' is not available.
The debugger engine 'Gdb engine' will be used as a fallback.
Details. I could not stop the debuger at the break point. It looks strange.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Tools -> Options -> Tool Chains`, and tell us what you see. I have only ever used Qt with mingw, not Visual Studio, so I don't know if it will help, but look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5380663/428857) and its resolution.

Comment: For Mingwas Gccfor windows target, Debugger is pointing D:\QtSdk\pythongdb\python_2.7based\gdb-i686-pc-mingw32.exe. i cloned it as you said, but it did not allow duplicate entry as i is already pointing the required location. compiler is pointing D:\QtSdk\mingw\bin\mingw32-g++.exe and ABI is pointing x86-Windows-msys-pe-32bit

Answer (score -1):

It looks like there was a bug in QtSDK installer at some point. Firstly, try updating. Secondly, try this:

1. open Qt Creator and go to `Tools → Options... → Build & Run`, select `Tool Chains` tab;
2. there should be `Auto-detected` list, select in there `Mingw as GCC for Windows targets` and click `Clone` button;
3. Now select cloned tool chain, you should be able edit specific fields in the bottom;
4. Click `Browse...` right to `Debugger` field and select `%QTDIR%\pythongdb\python_2.7based\gdb-i686-pc-mingw32.exe`;
5. Save your edits, create a new project (don't forget to select cloned tool chain) and try debugging.

Does it work?

Comment: Already Debugger is pointing D:\QtSdk\pythongdb\python_2.7based\gdb-i686-pc-mingw32.exe. i cloned it as you said, but it did not allow duplicate entry as i is already pointing the required location.  compiler is pointing D:\QtSdk\mingw\bin\mingw32-g++.exe and ABI is pointing x86-Windows-msys-pe-32bit

Comment: Maybe you should just fully reinstall Qt.